# How to filter SQL Server DateTime using .NET Core WebAPI with OData v4

Tags: asp.net-core, odata, asp.net-core-webapi, odata-v4

I am running a simple .NET Core WebApi application with OData Query v4 and SQL Server 2012.

This works, but it's extremely slow:

```
GET /api-endpoint?$filter=date(MyDateTimeField) ge 2018-01-01&$top=100
```

SQL Query generated by the URL above:

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM MyTable WHERE ((((DATEPART(year, [MyDateTimeField]) * 10000) + (DATEPART(month, [MyDateTimeField]) * 100)) + DATEPART(day, [MyDateTimeField])) >= (((2018 * 10000) + (1 * 100)) + 1))
```

When I try to do this:

```
GET /api-endpoint?$filter=MyDateTimeField ge 2018-01-01T00:00:00.00Z&$top=100
```

It generates the following SQL query:

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM MyTable WHERE [MyDateTimeField] > '2018-01-01T00:00:00.0000000'
```

Which returns this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

**What would the OData Query syntax be to generate a SQL query similiar to this?**

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM MyTable WHERE [MyDateTimeField] > '2018-01-01'
```

Comment: Not sure whether I'm asking a stupid question: Why not use `datetime2` ? If you use `datetime2`, you query should work fine.

Comment: Hi @itminus, it's a legacy database and I don't have permission to change it.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the field of `MyDateTimeField` is **`datetime`** instead of **`datatime2`**, decorate the `MyDateTimeField` with a column annotation **`[Column(TypeName="datetime")]`** firstly :

```
public class MyTable
{
    // ...  other props

    [Column(TypeName="datetime")]
    public DateTime MyDateTimeField {get;set;}
}
```

To query with `datetime`, **`cast`** it into **`DateTimeOffset`**:

```
?$filter=MyDateTimeField ge cast(2018-01-01T00:00:00.00Z,Edm.DateTimeOffset)
```

The generated `sql` is something like :

```
  SELECT ..., [$it].[MyDateTimeField], 
  FROM [MyTable] AS [$it]
  WHERE [$it].[MyDateTimeField] >= '2018-01-01T08:00:00.000'
```

Note the `datetime` above is **`2018-01-01T08:00:00.000`** instead of **`2018-01-01T00:00:00.0000000`**.

**A screenshot of Demo:**

[image]

Comment: thank you - I can't believe ODatav4 just dropped DateTime like "ah no ones using it" - sure our databases would be better using DateTimeOffset but some decisions were made before ODataV4 and forcing devs to just "convert all datetime columns to datetimeoffsets" is just plain rude - it should at least work the same way it does in V3 - anyway you may have saved my bacon :)

Answer (score 1):

After drowning incredulous in my own frustration I finally found a solution which would not force my api consumers to cast the DateTime string in an, ugly, verbose, disturbing expression.
I also want my model to transparently look like using *DateTimeOffset* instead of *DateTime*, this will allow me in the future to refactor the database and finally use DateTimeOffset even if so far I don't need to handle time zones.
My limitation is that I cannot update my legacy database and so here is the solution.

**Is this solution for you?**

This solution is useful only if:

- You cannot (or want to) update your db column type (if you can you should and solve the problem)
- You use or can change you entities to use *DateTimeOffset* instead of *DateTime* (If it is a new api consider doing this to comply with odata standard and allowing you to refactor in the future the underlay database)
- You don't need to handle different time zones (this can be done but you need to work on the solution to do it)
- You use EF Core >= 2.1

**Solution**

1. Update your entity using *DateTimeOffset*

```
public class MyEntity {
    [...]
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset ModifiedDateTime { get; set; }
    [...]
}
```

2. Create a [ValueConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.storage.valueconversion.valueconverter?view=efcore-3.0)

```
public static class ValueConvertes
{
    public static ValueConverter<DateTimeOffset, DateTime> DateTimeToDateTimeOffset =
        new ValueConverter<DateTimeOffset, DateTime>(
            model => model.DateTime, 
            store => DateTime.SpecifyKind(store, DateTimeKind.UTC));
}
```

3. Update your model mapping

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<QuestionQML> builder)            
{
    builder.ToTable("MyEntityTable");
    builder.Property(e => e.CreatedDateTime)
       .HasColumnName("CreatedDateTime") // On DB datetime Type
       .HasConversion(ValueConvertes.DateTimeToDateTimeOffset);
    builder.Property(e => e.ModifiedDateTime)
       .HasColumnName("ModifiedDateTime") // On DB datetime Type
       .HasConversion(ValueConvertes.DateTimeToDateTimeOffset);
    [...]          
}
```

This allow you to filter in the following ways:

> ?$filter=CreatedDateTime gt 2010-01-25T02:13:40Z
>   ?$filter=CreatedDateTime gt 2010-01-25T02:13:40.01234Z
>   ?$filter=CreatedDateTime gt 2010-01-25

Special thanks to [chris-clark](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/136#issuecomment-416634837)

EDIT:
Corrected code DateTimeKind.UTC can be used when the datetime stored in the database is in UTC, if you store in a different timezone you need to set the Kind to the timezone you use, but this changes the way your datetimes will be shown in the results, showing for UK Timezone, for example, Z(GMT time) or +01:00 (BST time.